# Html syntax to make it work properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have got this part of code which represents an item in this bunch of items:
http://www.gosu.cz

```
<script> //this script is used to set A TAG href via it's ID
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img').click(function () {
        var alt = $(this).attr("alt")
        var strLink = "link&Key=" + alt;
        document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href",strLink);
    });
});
```

```
<!-- Least Content -->
<main id="least">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="least-preview"></div> //div used to show selected item
        <ul class="gallery start" id="gallery_w">

    <!-- item -->
    //definition of item, which carry additional informations in data-caption
    //However having A TAG using ID to set HREF does't work when ID is not in ""
    <li class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="http://placehold.it/857x712" data-caption="<h3>Header</h3> <p>description </p> <a id=link>Zobrazit produkty</a>"  />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/857x712" class="img-responsive" alt="chair" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- /item -->
```

and if you click on first item (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBWad.jpg) which I work on right now you can see displayed data-caption (which can be seen in this code). What I need is to make that A TAG working via id. It normaly works when it's used outside tag parameters but I can't run it inside parameter. Where is my syntax mistake please?

Comment: Provide your relevant code here

Comment: What do you mean with relevant code ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write provide everything you can so that someone doesn't have to visit your website and view the source themselves. People tend to care more for helping, when they see you care more for your question.

Comment: I think you main problem is that you try to put stuff like: <h3>Header</h3> <p>description </p> <a id=link>Zobrazit produkty</a> into  data-caption. Try to rather create some kind of object with id's and data. and reference that id in you data-caption tag

Comment: To be honest I haven't programme few years now and this is bought. So for my confidence I would rather stick with the way it's writen and do as small modifications as possible so I dont screw that up :D :)